# Error 502 with conflicting server name and (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

Mywebsite.co.uk displays a 502 Error. Running `sudo tail -F /var/log/nginx/error.log` outputs:

```
2020/10/22 09:42:13 [warn] 200096#200096: conflicting server name "mywebsite.co.uk" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
    2020/10/22 09:42:13 [warn] 200107#200107: conflicting server name "mywebsite.co.uk" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
    2020/10/22 09:42:29 [error] 200110#200110: *1 open() "/home/user/mywebsite-app/static/admin/css/fonts.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 37.70.203.239, server: mywebsite.co.uk, request: "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1", host: "mywebsite.co.uk", referrer: "http://mywebsite.co.uk/"
    2020/10/22 09:42:50 [crit] 200110#200110: *4 connect() to unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 37.70.203.239, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx"
    2020/10/22 09:42:51 [crit] 200110#200110: *4 connect() to unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 37.70.203.239, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx"
    2020/10/22 09:43:00 [error] 200110#200110: *1 open() "/home/user/mywebsite-app/static/admin/css/fonts.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 37.70.203.239, server: mywebsite.co.uk, request: "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1", host: "mywebsite.co.uk", referrer: "http://mywebsite.co.uk/"
    2020/10/22 09:43:24 [error] 200110#200110: *1 open() "/home/user/mywebsite-app/static/admin/css/fonts.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 37.70.203.239, server: mywebsite.co.uk, request: "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1", host: "mywebsite.co.uk", referrer: "http://mywebsite.co.uk/"
    2020/10/22 09:57:01 [crit] 200110#200110: *10 connect() to unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 103.42.252.150, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:80"
    2020/10/22 10:07:00 [error] 200110#200110: *12 open() "/home/user/mywebsite-app/static/admin/css/fonts.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 37.70.203.239, server: mywebsite.co.uk, request: "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1", host: "mywebsite.co.uk", referrer: "http://mywebsite.co.uk/"
    2020/10/22 10:07:28 [crit] 200110#200110: *15 connect() to unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 37.70.203.239, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx"
```

I suppose it might have somethint to do with `gunicorn.socket` being in `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket` and not at `unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket`? Where do I need to change this? What else might be the problem?

My gunicorn.socket:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=user
EnvironmentFile=/home/user/mywebsite-app/env
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/mywebsite-app
ExecStart=/home/user/env/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
         mywebsite-app.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: It means you have two `server` blocks with the same `listen` and `server_name` values. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and identify the duplicate. Some editors leave backup files behind that are inadvertently included.

Comment: @RichardSmith you were right I had 2 /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp s. Deleted one but still reproduce the above error without the first output line

Answer (score 0):

use unix:/run/gunicorn.sock in upstream or proxy_pass not your unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket